# Actors created with TestActorRef cannot be resolved sometimes

Tags: scala, akka

If an actor is created using TestActorRef.apply(), it might be failed to resolve by calling `actorSystem.actorSelection.resolveOne` within a Future.

The doc for TestActorRef says it can be used in single-threaded environment, but I wonder what is the certain reason for the following test to fail.

Akka version: 2.4.16

Minimal test that fails, if run 1000 times with error `akka.actor.ActorNotFound: Actor not found for: ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://test-system/), Path(/user/test-actor)]`:

```
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorSystem, Props}
import akka.testkit.TestActorRef
import akka.util.Timeout
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

@RunWith(classOf[JUnitRunner])
class TestActorRefTest extends FunSuite with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("test-system")
  implicit val timeout = Timeout.durationToTimeout(3.seconds)

  override def afterAll(): Unit = actorSystem.terminate()

  test("find just created actors") {

    val actorRef = TestActorRef(Props(new TestActor()), "test-actor")
    val timeout = Timeout.durationToTimeout(3.seconds)

    val findFuture = actorSystem.actorSelection(actorRef.path).resolveOne()(timeout)
    Await.result(findFuture, 10.seconds)
  }
}

private class TestActor extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ =>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted with a big warning box in the docs [here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html#synchronous-testing-testactorref) the test actor ref is for synchronous testing only and cannot safely be used in any async tests (such as the shown one doing actor selection).

Comment: In this example, TestActorRef is not used in place of error.

Comment: You are trying to look the testActorRef up using actorSelection, so it is in fact used in the place of error.

Comment: Being searched for doest not mean being used.

Comment: If you dig into the Akka sources you will see that `ActorSelection.resolveOne` is implemented through message sending, just that it returns a `Future` should tell you that it is asynchronous.